# Location of Blend Door Actuator in 2003 Chevy Malibu

Tags: ac, chevrolet, heat, malibu, n-body

I am fairly certain that my Blend Door actuator is faulty.  I get all hot air in my car, which is great for the winter, not so much for the summer.

I want to replace it, and followed directions on [autozone](http://www.autozone.com/autozone/repairinfo/repairguide/repairGuideContent.jsp?pageId=0996b43f80371191) and other Q/A sites, however, I think the instructions are for a different model year.  I removed the left closeout panel, and what I thought was the knee bolster, but can't find anything that looks like the blend door actuator.  Is it somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sounds like](http://www.chevymalibuforum.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-8756.html) there might more than one blend door.  I guess you're looking for the heater blend door?  Have you gone through chevymalibuforum.com?  From [this](http://www.chevymalibuforum.com/forums/showthread.php?t=7555), you might be able to get at it through the glovebox?

When all else fails, consult the factory service manual. Unfortunately, in [your case](http://www.helminc.com/helm/Result.asp?Style=helm&Mfg=GMC&Make=CHV&Model=MALI&Year=2003&Category=1&Keyword=&Module=&selected_media=), it's $200 new.  They sometimes turn up on ebay, but it looks like there is a lot of crap to wade through at the moment in the search results.

If you go messing around behind the dash, even if you're going in through the glovebox, safe the airbags.  You can disconnect the battery and wait a few minutes (make sure this won't lock you out of your radio), pull the SIR fuse(s), or open the deployment loop connectors (something else to go hunting for).

Answer (score 2):

I forgot to answer this.  I found the actuator behind the globebox door.  It was actually very easy to install once I found it!

Comment: Which side does the Actuator face? Does the backside face the right drivers door?
Can you give a breif description as to something to assist me in locating the Blend Door Actuator?
I am looking for mine, but just had knee surgery so kind of tough to be looking for it.
Thanks in advanced,
Ron

Comment: It's on the left side of the glove box. You have to take off the entire glove box to get to it.